# Typescript - Type 'string' is not assignable to union type of strings

Tags: typescript

I have a component that gets a prop that is of a union type:

```
export const RoleTag = ({ roleType }: { roleType: "BA" | "BM" | "BP" | "FR" | "RM" }) => {
    return (
        <Tag variant={ROLE_TAGS[roleType]} size="small" className="w-8 mr-2 rounded">
            {rolleType}
        </Tag>
    );
};
```

`Tag` component has defined variant as union as well:

```
export interface TagProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement> {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  /**
   * Changes visual profile of tag
   */
  variant:
    | "warning"
    | "warning-filled"
    | "error"
    | "error-filled"
    | "info"
    | "info-filled"
    | "success"
    | "success-filled"
    | "neutral"
    | "neutral-filled"
    | "alt1"
    | "alt1-filled"
    | "alt2"
    | "alt2-filled"
    | "alt3"
    | "alt3-filled";
  /**
   * @default "medium"
   */
  size?: "medium" | "small" | "xsmall";
}
```

I am computing variant by using ROLE_TAG constant:

```
export enum RolleType {
    BM = "BM",
    BP = "BP",
    BA = "BA",
    RM = "RM",
    FR = "FR",
}

export const ROLE_TAGS = {
    [RolleType.BM]: "success",
    [RolleType.BP]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.BA]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.RM]: "alt3",
    [RolleType.FR]: "alt3",
};
```

But, with the current setup I get a Typescript error:

```
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"success" | "alt1" | "alt3" | "warning" | "warning-filled" | "error" | "error-filled" | "info" | "info-filled" | "success-filled" | "neutral" | "neutral-filled" | "alt1-filled" | "alt2" | "alt2-filled" | "alt3-filled"'.
```

What am I doing wrong here, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const ROLE_TAGS = {
    [RolleType.BM]: "success",
    [RolleType.BP]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.BA]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.RM]: "alt3",
    [RolleType.FR]: "alt3",
};
```

Since this doesn't have an explicit type, typescript infers one. When it sees strings, it assumes the type should be `string`, so the inferred type is:

```
{
    BM: string;
    BP: string;
    BA: string;
    RM: string;
    FR: string;
}
```

Since the type for the properties is `string`, the information about the specific values is lost. So when you try to use a `string` where a more specific value is required, you get an error.

If you want typescript to be stricter in its inference you can add `as const` to tell typescript that the values will never change:

```
export const ROLE_TAGS = {
    [RolleType.BM]: "success",
    [RolleType.BP]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.BA]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.RM]: "alt3",
    [RolleType.FR]: "alt3",
} as const;

// Inferred type:
//{
//    readonly BM: "success";
//    readonly BP: "alt1";
//    readonly BA: "alt1";
//    readonly RM: "alt3";
//    readonly FR: "alt3";
//}
```

---

A more advanced option is to use the new `satisfies` operator on ROLE_TAGS, as in:

```
export const ROLE_TAGS = {
    [RolleType.BM]: "success",
    [RolleType.BP]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.BA]: "alt1",
    [RolleType.RM]: "alt3",
    [RolleType.FR]: "alt3",
} satisfies { [key in RolleType]: TagProps['variant'] };
```

This tells typescript that it should infer the exact values, but it should also verify whether the resulting type matches with `{ [key in RolleType]: TagProps['variant'] }`. So if, for example, you add a new value to `RolleType`, ROLE_TAGS will start to show an error because it no longer has all the properties it needs. Or if someone edits `variant` so that "success" is no longer a legal value, you'll again get an error on `RolleType`.